# How access lan when I run wireguard in docker?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, docker, wireguard

I have vps with ubuntu onboard and installed wireguard. Also I have a home network: router + several laptops. I want connect my router to vps and have access from vps to any laptops.

I run wirequard with docker compose:

```
  wireguard:
    image: linuxserver/wireguard
    container_name: wireguard
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
      - SYS_MODULE
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London #set correct timezone
      - SERVERPORT=51820 #optional
      - PEERS=green #optional
      - PEERDNS=auto #optional
      - ALLOWEDIPS=0.0.0.0/0 #Peer addresses allowed
      - INTERNAL_SUBNET=10.13.13.0/24 #Subnet used in VPN tunnel
      - SERVERURL=example.org #Wireguard VPN server address
    volumes:
      - ~/apps/wireguard/config:/config
      - /lib/modules:/lib/modules
    ports:
      - 51820:51820/udp
```

This is my wg0.conf:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.13.1
ListenPort = 51820
PrivateKey = 
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
# peer_green
PublicKey = 
PresharedKey = 
AllowedIPs = 10.13.13.2/32, 192.168.1.0/24
```

Peer config:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.13.13.2
PrivateKey = 
ListenPort = 51820
DNS = 10.13.13.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = 
PresharedKey = 
Endpoint = example.org:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

I can connect to wireguard with router, but I can't ping router or any devices from vps.
Also I doesn't see any router on my ps with "ip route".
How to make LAN reachable from my vps or my laptop connected to vps?

[image]

Comment: sounds like you need to add a route to your LAN using wg0 as its interface.

Comment: do you have any example?

Comment: `ip route add {LAN_NETWORK/MASK} via {GATEWAYIP} dev wg0` https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ip-route-add-network-command-for-linux-explained/

Comment: how to make this ip route permanent? (I use ubuntu)

Comment: did adding the route resolve the issue?

Comment: No, I got this: PING 192.168.1.63 (192.168.1.63) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.13.13.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

Comment: perhaps it would help us to see a map of your network, with IP ranges for each link. also describe your wireguard connection. it sounds like you are doing site-to-point, where the VPS container is acting as the server, and your router the client. it may be helpful to reverse that, so that your router is the server and your VPS connects to it.

Comment: I can't reverse my connection, because I need to connect another network to my vps

Comment: Can I ask why you want to run wireguard, of all things, in a docker container?

Comment: I want to have all configuration in one place for easier migration/backups

Answer (score 1):

Do not use AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0  use 10.13.13.0/24 and use PersistentKeepalive = 25. If you still cannot connection over vpn, you should do masquearate docker tunnel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).